# Javascript imports (redux toolkit)

Tags: javascript, redux-toolkit

In the [official redux toolkit documentation/tutorial](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start), there's this file (counterSlice.js)

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: {
    value: 0
  },
  reducers: {
    increment: state => {
      // Redux Toolkit allows us to write "mutating" logic in reducers. It
      // doesn't actually mutate the state because it uses the Immer library,
      // which detects changes to a "draft state" and produces a brand new
      // immutable state based off those changes
      state.value += 1
    },
    decrement: state => {
      state.value -= 1
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload
    }
  }
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions

export default counterSlice.reducer
```

The reducer is then imported in the store:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import counterReducer from '../features/counter/counterSlice'

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer
  }
})
```

As I cannot see any reference to 'counterReducer' in the counterSlice.js file, I assume the 'counterReducer' in the import:

```
import counterReducer from '../features/counter/counterSlice'
```

is an arbitratry name and could be any other name of our choice, for example:

```
import counterSliceReducer from '../features/counter/counterSlice'
```

Is that correct?

Also, where is this 'reducer' in the default export coming from?

```
export default counterSlice.reducer
```

The counterSlice element contains 'reducers' object, not 'reducer'. Is that pulled from under the hood?

Thanks

Comment: About your last point: `createSlice()` return `counterSlice` object which has `reducer` property, not `reducers`. See [this](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/61ec24c3a7c06f08e9b1bcdead63c01fc43cf3b6/src/createSlice.ts#L305)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any name if the imported module uses the `export default xxx` method to export the module.

`createSlice` will return an object that looks like:

```js
{
    name : string,
    reducer : ReducerFunction,
    actions : Record<string, ActionCreator>,
    caseReducers: Record<string, CaseReducer>
}
```

Take a look at [this docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#return-value)

Answer (score 1):

> I assume the 'counterReducer' in the import: 
> `import counterReducer from '../features/counter/counterSlice'` 
> is an arbitratry name and could be any other name of our choice

You are correct, it is an ES6 feature, a default export can be imported with any name. see: [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#description)

> Also, where is this 'reducer' in the default export coming from?
> `export default counterSlice.reducer`
> The counterSlice element contains 'reducers' object, not 'reducer'. Is that pulled from under the hood?

`createSlice` API returns an object in a form:

```js
{
    name : string,
    reducer : ReducerFunction,
    actions : Record<string, ActionCreator>,
    caseReducers: Record<string, CaseReducer>
}
```

`counterSlice.reducer` is the reducer function, it needs to be exported and then passed to the store.